# HTML/CSS float issues

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a layout like this picture below but I'm not doing very well.

[image: Picture to the left, div to the right]

As you can see, I'm trying to put a picture on the left and a somewhat-complicated div on the right. So far, I've been trying with `float` without much luck:

```css
#image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#text {
  float: left;
}
.column {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  padding-left:10px;
}
.column::after {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<div id="main_section">
  <img id="image" src="http://tny.im/knQ" alt="link picture" />
  <div id="text">
    <h2> This is the main overhead title </h2>
    <p class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus id lacinia arcu. Sed risus ligula, placerat varius accumsan quis, gravida ut erat.</p>
    <p class="column">Maecenas ante ex, dignissim a scelerisque euismod, fermentum at elit. Curabitur convallis, sapien sit amet facilisis interdum.</p>
    <h2> This is the end of the section </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry to ask a trivial question, I'm googling all over and can't get this to work.

Comment: You don't need `float` for this. Is there a reason you're not using `flex` or` grid`?

Comment: @Dai The only reason I'm trying `float` is because I keep seeing it as I'm googling around. I'll try looking into `flex` and `grid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `#text` takes `100%` `width`. So it comes below the `image`. If you set a specific width for `#text`, it will `float`.

```
#text {
  width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this once

```css
#image {
padding-top:100px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;    
}
   
.column {
  width: 20%;
  padding-left:10px;
}
.column::after {
  clear: both
}

#main_section{
display: flex;
}
.wrapper{
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_section">
  <img id="image" src="http://tny.im/knQ" alt="link picture" />
  <div id="text">
    <h2> This is the main overhead title </h2>
    <div class="wrapper"><p class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus id lacinia arcu. Sed risus ligula, placerat varius accumsan quis, gravida ut erat.</p>
    <p class="column">Maecenas ante ex, dignissim a scelerisque euismod, fermentum at elit. Curabitur convallis, sapien sit amet facilisis interdum.</p></div>
    
    <h2> This is the end of the section </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Floats inside a flexbox are useless. Therefore the CSS can be optimized

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have solved it with the help of the `flex` property. If you want to get two elements side by side then flex property is easy and very useful in comparison to float & it sets the flexible length on flexible items.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/bysj29tx/1/

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

#image {
  height: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-self: flex-start;
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.row {
  margin: 0px -5px;
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex" id="main_section">
  <img id="image" src="http://tny.im/knQ" alt="link picture" />
  <div id="text">
    <h2> This is the main overhead title </h2>
    <div class="row d-flex">
     <p class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus id lacinia arcu. Sed risus ligula, placerat varius accumsan quis, gravida ut erat.</p>
      <p class="column">Maecenas ante ex, dignissim a scelerisque euismod, fermentum at elit. Curabitur convallis, sapien sit amet facilisis interdum.</p>
    </div>
     <h2> This is the end of the section </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```